# Modify request URI in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, uri, interceptor

I have a spring mvc based application. I want to modify the request URI before it reaches controller. For example, RequestMapping for controller is "abc/xyz" but the request coming is "abc/1/xyz". I want to modify incoming request to map it to controller.

Solution1: Implement interceptor and modify incoming request URI. But the problem here is that as there is no controller matching the URI pattern "abc/1/xyz", it does not even goes to interceptor.(I might be missing something to enable it if its there)
Get around for  it could be to have both of URI as request mapping for controller.

What other solutions could be there? Is there a way to handle this request even before it comes to spring. As in handle it at filter in web.xml, i am just making it up.

Comment: A request cannot be modified.

Comment: request cannot be modified?? Do you mean request URI or the whole request object?

Comment: you can create a new method on this controller to match an url like '/abc/{param}/xyz'. Even you can try to create a new controller matching this kind of URL and redirect to the controller you need.

Comment: You can change almost nothing of the request object, including the URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a servlet `Filter` which wraps the `HttpServletRequest` and returns a different value for the method `getRequestURI`. Something like that:

```
public class RequestURIOverriderServletFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getRequestURI() {
                 // return what you want
            }
        }, response);
    }

    // ...

 }
```

The servlet filter configuration must be added into the `web.xml`.

But sincerly, there is probably other way to solve your problems and you should not do this unless you have very good reasons.

Comment: This could be one solution. What i ended up doing is, creating a filter and connected it to spring using DelegatingFilterProxy. THis gives me power to autowire spring beans.

From this filter i used `request.getRequestDispatcher(modifiedURI).forward(request, response)`

One problem i faced with this was that exception thrown in filter is not caught by exceptionhandler of spring.

Answer (score 1):

in order to achieve this you should replace every place that affected when you calling uri.

the place that not mentioned is **INCLUDE_SERVLET_PATH_ATTRIBUTE** which is internally is accessed when going deeper.

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthFilter.class);
private final String API_PREFIX = "/api";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
    if (requestURI.startsWith(API_PREFIX)) {
        String redirectURI = requestURI.substring(API_PREFIX.length());
        StringBuffer redirectURL = new StringBuffer(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString().replaceFirst(API_PREFIX, ""));
        filterChain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getRequestURI() {
                return redirectURI;
            }

            @Override
            public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
                return redirectURL;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getAttribute(String name) {
                if(WebUtils.INCLUDE_SERVLET_PATH_ATTRIBUTE.equals(name))
                    return redirectURI;
                return super.getAttribute(name);
            }
        }, response);
        
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Posting working code as an example is great; however sometimes it helps more to just answer the OP's questions and nudging them a bit to understand the underlying principles...

Comment: or just `request.setAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_SERVLET_PATH_ATTRIBUTE, redirectURI);`

Comment: @ChristianSeverin, okay, next time i will do like you suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL Re-Write which are specifically meant for this purpose i.e. transform one request URI to another URI based on some regex.