# Spring mvc interceptor Basics

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring and currently working on a spring application.
I am very confused regarding the spring interceptor and Interceptor in Spring security.

I have below doubts.
1. What is the use of Interceptor ? Is it used to modify the requested url or to validate the url ?
2. Is it possible that through interceptor i can modify my url /Test/MyTest to /Test/Intercept/MyTest ?
3. If Interceptor is only used to vaidate the url then only by url-pattern=/"somevalue" it will work or need to implement Interceptorhandler ?

Please help me out to understand these basic functionalities of interceptor.

I went through lot of sites but still not clear about all these concepts.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549093/modify-request-uri-in-spring-mvc) for information, might clear your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

An interceptor is somewhat like a filter. A filter processes the request and response around a servlet and an interceptor processes the request and optionally the model around a spring controller. Common uses are pre-processing a request to ensure that a condition is realized (`preHandle`), or populating the model with attributes common to different controller methods (`postHandle`). `afterCompletion` is mainly used to perform cleanup at the end of request processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Actually interceptor can do three things

            preHandle(…) – called just before the action
            postHandle(…) – called immediately after the action
            afterCompletion(…) – called just before sending response to view

        Best example of prehandle is-checking whether the user is logged in or not.


      Hope you have got some idea of interceptor
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC **Interceptor** is similar to **Servlet Fiter** Concept. Spring MVC provides ability to define set of classes called interceptor which will be called before and after a request being served. Interceptor will implement [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) which following thee methods need to be implemented:

1. **preHandle**() : Called before the handler execution
2. **postHandle**() : Called after the handler execution
3. **afterCompletion**() : Called after the complete request has finished

There is a good [tutorial by MKYONG](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) which I recommend you to have a look at it that I found it helpful in understanding the fundamental concept of interceptor. Hope that helps to get you started.